# How to add a label above each md-chip in md-chips?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material, md-chip

I would to like create a label above md-chip based on their type, however objects with similar type should be grouped under one label like this:

```
<span> Orange item: </span>
<md-chip> Carrot </md-chip>

Red item:
Red apple
Strawberry

Yellow item:
Banana

<span> Orange item: </span>
<md-chip> Tomato </md-chip>
```

My apologies that I can't embed image to show my needs but can only do in text.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<span>Orange object:</span>
<md-chips ng-model="arrayList | filter: {type: 'orange'}"
          md-removable="true">
    <md-chip-template>
        {{$chip.name}}
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>

<span>Red object:</span>
<md-chips ng-model="arrayList | filter: {type: 'red'}">
    <md-chip-template>
        {{$chip.name}}
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>

<span>Yellow object:</span>
<md-chips ng-model="arrayList | filter: {type: 'yellow'}">
    <md-chip-template>
        {{$chip.name}}
    </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

However, this would cause an **error** like this:

> angular.js:13550 [Error: [ngModel:nonassign]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign) Expression 'arrayList |
>   filter: {type: 'orange'}' is non-assignable. Element:

Are there other ways I can do to achieve the same?

**[Update]**
Assuming there is a second Orange item, a new label and md-chip for the second Orange item should be created right below the last Yellow item.. Have updated the example code.

Comment: `ng-model` you mean to `[(ngModel)]`? It is angular or angular js?

Comment: can you share you working code's link on stackblitz.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it is angularjs